# Bash - Log all commands and exit codes in a script

Tags: bash, logging

I have a long (~2,000 lines) script that I'm trying to log for future debugging. Right now I have:

```
function log_with_time()
{
    while read a; do
        echo `date +'%H:%M:%S.%4N '` " $a" >> $LOGFILE
    done
}

exec 7> >(log_with_time)
BASH_XTRACEFD=7
PS4=' exit($?)ln:$LINENO: '
set -x
echo "helloWorld 1"
```

which gives me very nice logging for any and all commands that are run:

```
15:18:03.6359  exit(0)ln:28: echo 'helloWorld 1'
```

The issue that I'm running into is that xtrace seems to be asynchronous. With longer scripts, the log times fall behind the actual time the commands are called, and the exit code doesn't match the logged command.

There has to be a better way to do this but I'd be happy if I could just synchronize xtrace.

...

**tldr:** How can I generally log the time, command and exit code for all commands in a script?

...

(First time posting, feedback appreciated)

**UPDATE:**

```
exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>>$LOGFILE
PS4=' time:$(date +%H:%M:%S.%4N) ln:$LINENO: '
set -x
fail()
{
    echo "fail" >> $LOGFILE
    return 1
}
trap 'echo exit:$? >> $LOGFILE' DEBUG
fail
```

solves all of my synchronization issues. exit codes and timestamps are working beautifully. My **only issue now** is one of formatting: the trap itself is getting reported by xtrace.

```
  time:18:30:07.6080 ln:27: fail
  time:18:30:07.6089 ln:12: echo fail
fail
  time:18:30:07.6126 ln:13: return 1
   time:18:30:07.6134 ln:28: echo exit:1
exit:1
```

I've tried setting +x in the trap but then set +x gets logged. If I could find a way to omit one line from xtrace, this log would be perfect.

Comment: What's async is your process substitution. Anything in `>(...)` is on the other side of a FIFO, running in its own process. The actual write to `BASH_XTRACEFD` is itself fully synchronous.

Comment: Anyhow, you don't need it -- you can set a `PS4` that inserts the date itself.

Comment: ...btw, as a stylistic note -- `function funcname() {` is a mix of POSIX sh and ancient-ksh declaration conventions (the former is just `funcname() {`, the second is `function funcname {`), and compatible with neither. It's best practice to pick one or the other -- I strongly suggest the POSIX form, as bash's ksh-esque function declaration syntax doesn't actually have the same semantics that format had in ksh (where it made variables defined in functions local-by-default).

Comment: ...the other thing you could do, by the way, is just direct *everything else* through that same process substitution. What makes things effectively async is that some contents go straight to the TTY (or otherwise your preexisting output destination), and others go through the process substitution; if everything goes through the same pipeline, it's synchronous again.

Comment: ...as another aside, modern bash has `printf %(%H:%M:%S)T -1` to emit the current time without all the overhead of forking off a subshell and then using an `exec`-family syscall to replace that subshell with a copy of `/usr/bin/date` (not to mention setting up a pair of FIFOs to read that subshell's output, &c).

Comment: (and see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: function declaration syntax).

Comment: Rolled back the title, while synchronizing my xtrace output is a possible solution, the more general question is "How can I log what I need in Bash"

Comment: If you just want commands and exit codes, consider a DEBUG trap.

Comment: Put the `$?` *before* the `date`. And btw, please point out issues with answers in comments on those answers, vs edits to the question; that way the person who posted the answer gets notified when such a comment is created.

Comment: Yes, the return codes being offset is expected, and unavoidable. The PS4 entry is logged when a command is *started*, not when it finishes, so its exit status isn't (and can't be) known yet. Same for a `DEBUG` trap, or *any other* logging mechanism that happens at beginning vs completion of a command's execution.

Comment: ...you can postprocess, of course, but in doing so you'll destroy synchronization unless you push the content you're trying to synchronize against through the same pipeline. And if you trade out PS4 for an alternate mechanism that only logs after you *do* have an exit status available, you'll no longer have a command's output logged below the command used to start it.

Comment: I would be fine with seperate logs for beginning and end. Log time line and command as I do now, and independently log the return code once it's available. xtrace takes care of the kickoff nicely but I don't know how I could report when commands finish

Comment: A DEBUG trap will do the job, somewhat. Lots of annoying caveats and places where behavior differs between shell releases and on optional settings (such as the state of the `functrace` flag).

Comment: I found your question well constructed and interesting, very good first post ;-) .

Comment: ...btw, would a newline after your `prior-exit` and before the reference to your new command suffice? `PS4=$' exit: $?\n time: $(date +%H:%M:%S.%4N) ln:$LINENO: '`, f/e.

Comment: One issue with the prior-exit approach: I had a function called fail which echo'ed fail and returned 1 and a function called success which echo'ed success and returned 0. The resultant log for 'fail; succcess' read that at 'success' and the subsequent 'echo success' $? was 1. So here, saying that $? was the prior-exit is not accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per conversation with Charles Duffy in the comments to whom all credit is given:

Process substitution >(...) is asynchronous, allowing the log writing to fall behind and out of sync with the xtrace.
Instead use:

```
exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>>$LOGFILE
PS4=' time:$(date +%H:%M:%S.%4N) ln:$LINENO: '
```

for synchronously logging the time and line.

Furthermore, xtrace is triggered before running the command, making it a bad candidate for capturing exit codes. Instead use:

```
trap 'echo exit:$? >> $LOGFILE' DEBUG
```

to log the exit codes of each command since trap triggers on command completion. Note that this won't report on every step in a function call like xtrace will. (could use some help with the phrasing here)

No solution yet for omitting the trap from xtrace, but it's good enough:

```
LOGFILE="SomeFile.log"

exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>>$LOGFILE
PS4=' time:$(date +%H:%M:%S.%4N) ln:$LINENO: '
set -x

fail() # test function that returns 1
{
    echo "fail" >> $LOGFILE
    return 1
}
 success() # test function that returns 0
{
    echo "success" >> $LOGFILE
    return 0
}

trap 'echo $? >> $LOGFILE' DEBUG

fail
success

echo "complete"
```

yields:

```
  time:14:10:22.2686 ln:21: trap 'echo $? >> $LOGFILE' DEBUG
   time:14:10:22.2693 ln:23: echo 0
0
  time:14:10:22.2736 ln:23: fail
  time:14:10:22.2741 ln:12: echo fail
fail
  time:14:10:22.2775 ln:13: return 1
   time:14:10:22.2782 ln:24: echo 1
1
  time:14:10:22.2830 ln:24: success
  time:14:10:22.2836 ln:17: echo success
success
  time:14:10:22.2873 ln:18: return 0
   time:14:10:22.2881 ln:26: echo 0
0
  time:14:10:22.2912 ln:26: echo complete
```

Answer (score 2):

The async behavior is coming from the process substitution -- anything in `>(...)` is running in its own subshell on the other end of a FIFO. Since it's a separate process, it's inherently unsynchronized.

You don't need `log_with_time` here at all, though, and so you don't need `BASH_XTRACEFD` redirecting to a process substitution in the first place. Consider:

```
# aside: $(date ...) has a *huge* amount of performance overhead here. Personally, I'd
#        advise against using it, unless you really need all that precision; $SECONDS will
#        be orders-of-magnitude cheaper.
PS4=' prior-exit:$? time:$(date +%H:%M:%S.%4N) ln:$LINENO: '
```

...thereafter:

```
$ true
 prior-exit:0 time:16:01:17.2509 ln:28: true
$ false
 prior-exit:0 time:16:01:18.4242 ln:29: false
$ false
 prior-exit:1 time:16:01:19.2963 ln:30: false
$ true
 prior-exit:1 time:16:01:20.2159 ln:31: true
$ true
 prior-exit:0 time:16:01:20.8650 ln:32: true
```

Comment: After failed formatting attempts in my comment, I've updated my answer to reflect my latest attempt. (Thanks by the way for all of your help so far)

Comment: aside from not aligning properly in some instances, prior-exit isn't really acceptable in terms of readability

Comment: `prior-exit` is what your original code did too -- I'm just providing a more accurate label.